# Send a PHP array to a JS Module, "import" problems

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm making a website to learn PHP and Javascript/JQuery, i don't have much experience yet and i'm trying to understand what's the best structure to implement

PHP creates an array of strings 
i can access the array from index.php via json_encode
then i want to send the array to a function in a class which is in a .mjs file
the problem is that in the index.php file, by the *script* tags i can't import the module, and if i use *script type="module"* i can use the import 
but i get this error:

*Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of ""* in main.mjs::1

the MDN reference the mjs extension is used to prevent that.
that's why i'm stuck.

server directory looks like this:

- index.php
- js/main.mjs
- js/index.mjs

Code snippets:

**index.php**

```
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Website</title>

      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
      <script src="js/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
      <script src="js/main.mjs" type="module"></script>

      <script type="module">

        import {start_index} from "./js/main.mjs";
        initialize();

        function initialize()
        {
          var arr = <?php echo json_encode($images_arr); ?>;
          start_index(arr);
        }

      </script>

    </head>
```

**main.mjs**

```
    function start_index(arr)
    {
      import {gallery_manager} from './index.mjs';
      var gallery_mngr = new gallery_manager();
      gallery_mngr.initialize(arr);
    }

    export {start_index};
```

**index.mjs**

```
    class gallery_manager
    {
      constructor(){}

      var images = "";
      var placeholder = "../images/common/placeholder.png";

      public function initialize(arr)
      {
        images = arr;
        alert(images[0]);
      }

      function switchByTimer()
      {

      }

      function switchImage(new_image, direction)
      {

      }
    }

    export {gallery_manager};
```

Comment: Q: You're using a web server, correct?  Q: What kind of web servier?  Apache2/Linux?  IIS Express local Windows PC? Something else?  STRONG SUGGESTION: familiarize yourself with [Chrome Developer Tools: ](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools).  Carefully examine the actual HTML being sent.  ALSO: consider changing "mjs" to "js".

Comment: I'm using XAMPP with Apache, also, i'm using the mjs extension because the reference says i should, with modules

Comment: i found the information here, and i'm also following the examples from github. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules

Comment: thanks for the suggestion about Google Devtools, actually i was already using it to diagnose the errors, but i'm using an external text editor to edit the code (Atom)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to fix my code, paulsm4 has lit a spark in my brain

.mjs extension strangely does not work, i have no idea why it's advised to use that extension for javascript modules as it is stated in the MDN reference

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules

also, some of my JS code was broken, especially class variables and functions
because i'm still learning the syntax..
now it's working as supposed

index.php

```
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
      <script src="js/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
      <script src="js/main.js" type="module"></script>

      <script type="module">

        import start_index from "./js/main.js";
        initialize();

        function initialize()
        {
          var arr = <?php echo json_encode($images_arr); ?>;
          start_index(arr);
        }

      </script>
```

main.js

```
    import gallery_manager from './index.js';

    function start_index(arr)
    {
      var gallery_mngr = new gallery_manager(arr);
      gallery_mngr.initialize();
    }

    export default start_index;
```

index.js

```
    class gallery_manager
    {
      constructor(images, placeholder)
      {
          this.images = images;
          this.placeholder = "../images/common/placeholder.png";
      }

      initialize()
      {
        alert(this.images[0]);
      }

      switchByTimer()
      {

      }

      switchImage(new_image, direction)
      {

      }
    }

    export default gallery_manager;
```

Answer (score 0):

MAIN PROBLEM:

Your web server doesn't appear to "understand" what an "mjs" file is, so it isn't sending the appropriate MIME type in the response's HTTP header.

SUGGESTION: change ".mjs" to "js" and see if that helps.  "mjs" is oriented toward NodeJS.

IMPORTANT QUESTIONS:

Q: You're using a web server, correct?

Q: What kind of web servier? Apache2/Linux? IIS Express local Windows PC? Something else?

STRONG SUGGESTION: familiarize yourself with [Chrome Developer Tools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but this is not an answer, i was already working with the js extension, that's why i changed it to mjs.. also i've already answered why i tried the .mjs extension, the MDN reference says it should solve the MIME type problem, now i'm gonna try with .js again and see if it changes anything
about all the other question, i've already answered in the main comment section, i forgot to tag you anyway

Comment: Yes, it's "an answer".  There's nothing "strange" that your .mjs "doesn't work".  Disappointing, maybe.  But the *really* disappointing thing is that MDN mislead you into thinking it *should* work.  Very simply: 1) your browser's Javascript engine is expecting the correct MIME type, in the HTTP response header, 2) XAMMP Apache doesn't  "recognize" the .mjs extension, so it's not *providing* the correct MIME type.  3) Game over for this combination of browser and web server.  One possible workaround: configure Apache to associate .mjs with MIME type "text/javascript".